# Wallabyjs React testing

Tags: wallaby.js

How to use Wallabyjs with React + shallow rendering + jsdom + webpack with css loader?
It works if I am not importing css to my component and so not using webpack. To import css into the component I was trying to configure webpack with css loader, but getting final error 'window is not defined'.

Here is my current config for testing components, which does not require css:

```
module.exports = function (wallaby) {
return {
  files: [
    {pattern: 'node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',   instrument: false},
  {pattern: 'node_modules/react/dist/react-with-addons.js', instrument: false},

  'src/**/*.js'
],

tests: [
  'test/**/*Spec.js'
],

compilers: {
  '**/*.js': wallaby.compilers.babel()
},
env: {
  type: 'node'
},
testFramework: 'mocha',

bootstrap: function() {
  global.expect = require('chai').expect;
},

setup: function() {
  global.React = require("react");

  // Taken from https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/jsdom.md
  var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;

  var exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

  global.document = jsdom('');
  global.window = document.defaultView;
  Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
    if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
      exposedProperties.push(property);
      global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
    }
  });

  global.navigator = {
    userAgent: 'node.js'
  };
}
```

};
};

how can I modify it, so it supports importing css into the component?

Comment: You are using `env.type: node`, so it runs in node.js and can't import css, unless you register `.css` extension and tell node how to load it.

Comment: If you'd like to load css (and make some assertions about it in your tests), then you need to configure wallaby to use Webpack + css loader.